# Why have extra resistor in switch debounce circuit

Tags: capacitor, resistors, switches, debounce

I am using a Laird BL654 module in my project, and using the dev board schematic to help me.  On the reset switch they have an external pull-up of 10k (R112) (in addition to the internal one on the module of 13k), which I understand is to give robustness against ESD.  The capacitor C63 I understand is for debounce.  What is the 150 ohm resistor for (R34)? [image: Reset switch circuit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For many reasons. First of all, the external 10k pull-up is not connected by default, and the 10nF capacitor is not populated either. So forget that those exist.

Without knowing any details what the reset connection looks like in the module, it is quite typical for microcontrollers to have a capacitor on their reset pin, so inside the module the MCU could have a capacitor on the reset pin too.

If there is capacitance directly over a pushbutton, pushing the button would short the capacitor and it would discharge with a large current spike. These pushbuttons and capacitors are not rated for such large currents and repeated button pushing could damage the pushbutton contacts or the capacitor.

Also the pushbuttons are not perfect, there might be several rapid transitions shorting and releasing the button contacts when it is pushed. This causes rapid current changes, or high di/dt. The wiring has some inductance, so high di/dt causes voltage spikes due to the inductance, and the voltage spikes may exceed what the module reset pin tolerates without damage. Also there can be high rate of change in voltage dv/dt which can couple capacitively to neighbouring wires.

So when the button has resistance in series, it limits discharge current from any capacitances to safe level that the button and capacitors can handle. This will result in lower changes in current, which will lower the voltage spikes from inductances. Also dv/dt is lower so there is less coupling.

So in short, the resistor is there to limit and slow down current and voltage changes so they don't cause trouble or damage.

Answer (score 1):

R34 is to limit discharge current noise the switch. As the switch contacts bounce a few times they produce a tiny amount of local RF noise which the 10 nF capacitor suppresses. R34 takes this further and keeps the noise from the IC RESET pin. You do not even want the trace to the switch to have noise on it as it can migrate to adjacent traces. If the cap is not installed R34 still reduces slew rate to less RF is created.

Overall this is not much of a filter circuit, so possibly digital filters are used to be-bounce the switch.

Answer (score 0):

yes I agree that limiting the large current spikes with a 150 Ohm resistor will in the long term save the switche's contacts.